# Java generics issue with compareTo and inheritance

Tags: java, generics, inheritance, comparable, compareto

so I have a problem with my generics code. I've created class Person and Student extends Person. When I was trying to compare both students it suddenly perceived it as a Person and group number wasn't even included. Here is my Person class

```
public class Person implements Comparable<Person>{...
        public int compareTo(Person o) {
        if(this.name.compareTo(o.name) > 0 )
            return 1;
        else if(this.name.compareTo(o.name) < 0)
            return -1;
        else{
            if(this.age > o.age)
                return 1;   
            else if(this.age < o.age)
                return -1;
            else{
                return 0;}
        }
}
```

My Student, where compareTo seems quite similar but with additional group id

```
public class Student extends Person implements Comparable<Person>{
      public int compareTo(Student s) {

    if(this.name.compareTo(s.name) > 0 ){
        System.out.println(this + " > " + s);
        return 1;}

    else if(this.name.compareTo(s.name) < 0){
        System.out.println(this + " < " + s);
        return -1;}

    else{
        if(this.age > s.age){
            System.out.println(this + " > " + s);
            return 1;}

        else if(this.age < s.age){
            System.out.println(this + " < " + s);
            return -1;}

        else{
            if(groupId > s.groupId){
                System.out.println(this + " > " + s);
                return 1;
            }
            else if(groupId < s.groupId){
                System.out.println(this + " < " + s);
                return -1;}
            else{
                System.out.println(this + " = " + s);
                return 0;}

        }   
            } 
        }
```

And finally a Box class that is using generics to find maximum and minimum of these classes and other types.

```
    public class Box<T extends Comparable> extends ArrayList<T> {

public T min() {
            T t = get(0);   

            for(int i = 0; i < this.size(); i++){
                    if(t.compareTo(get(i)) > 0)
                        t = super.get(i);
                    }   
            return t;
        }
    }
```

I haven't shown you entire code, but I think it is enough. I've made Box object and still it is comparing them as Person not as Students.
Can someone explain what is the problem here?
Edit: my Array

```
Box<Student> bst = new Box<>();
        bst.add(new Student("Nowacka", 24, 100));        
        bst.add(new Student("Nowacka", 24, 300));
        bst.add(new Student("Nowacka", 24, 200));
        bst.print();
        System.out.println(bst.max());                                          // Student: Nowacka, 24, 300
```

the answer should be 300, yet is 100 and in Person's compareTo i've added earliel some System.out.println to see which method it is using

Comment: Show more of your `Student` class. How is `compareTo` method declared?

Comment: And what makes you think it's comparing as `Person`, not `Student`s? What does your list contain, exactly?

Comment: I think you will need to post [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Judging from snippets of code is invidious, the error may be somewhere else.

Comment: Inheritance doesn't work with Comparable. You should use Comparable only with the type of your class. In any other cases create Comparator and do whatever you need.

Comment: I've edited my post, put some example and shown entire student's compareTo method

Comment: @BogdanLukiyanchuk that is simply wrong. Inheritance does of course work with interfaces (and thus `Comparable`). The problem is that method calls are determined by the static type, not the runtime type.

Comment: if you want to shoot your leg, ofc it works

Comment: @BogdanLukiyanchuk My task was to do this with Comparable and I've done it before, but completely forgot how it works. :P

Answer (score 1):

Let us analyze what [`Comparable<T>`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html) actually needs and does. If `SomeClass implements Comparable<T>`, you are forced to implement a method `public int compareTo(T other)`. The `T` will become important in a second, keep it int he back of your head. This is what you did with your `Person`-class:

```
public class Person implements Comparable<Person> {
    // ...
    public int compareTo(Person o) {
    if (this.name.compareTo(o.name) > 0 ) {
        return 1;
    } else if (this.name.compareTo(o.name) < 0) {
        return -1;
    }
    else {
        if (this.age > o.age) {
            return 1;   
        } else if (this.age < o.age) {
            return -1;
        } else {
            return 0;
        }
    }
}
```

Now, let's examine the `Student`-class:

```
public class Student extends Person implements Comparable<Person>{
    public int compareTo(Student s) { 
        ...
    }
}
```

We implement `Comparable<Person>`, but we do not have a `public int compareTo(Person p)`, we only have a `public int compareTo(Student s)`. So why does it get compiled? Because we inherit `public int compareTo(Person p)` from `Person`. The method `public int compareTo(Student s)` is actually never used, at least not in the context of the `Comparable<Person>` interface.

Well then, let us `public class Student extends Person implements Comparable<Student>`! Sadly, the compiler does not like this. We cannot implement the same generic interface multiple times with different type parameters. We are stuck. As soon as a `Comparable` is implemented along the object hierachy, we cannot re-implement it.

It is tempting to override the `compareTo(...)` method. This, however, will break the contract of `Comparable`:

> The implementor must ensure `sgn(x.compareTo(y)) == -sgn(y.compareTo(x))` for all `x` and `y`. (This implies that `x.compareTo(y)` must throw an exception iff `y.compareTo(x)` throws an exception.)
>
> The implementor must also ensure that the relation is transitive: `(x.compareTo(y) > 0 && y.compareTo(z) > 0)` implies `x.compareTo(z) > 0`.
>
> Finally, the implementor must ensure that `x.compareTo(y) == 0` implies that `sgn(x.compareTo(z)) == sgn(y.compareTo(z))`, for all `z`.

Let us try to not break the contract. A possible implementation for your `Student` class may look like this:

```
// CAUTION! This implementation is BROKEN! Keep reading to learn why.
public class Student extends Person {
    @Override
    public int compareTo(Person that) {
        int comp = super.compareTo(that);
        if (comp == 0 && that instanceof Person == true) {
            Student thatStuden = ((Student) that);
            comp = ...
        }
        return comp;
    }
}
```

But this solution breaks part of the contract of `Comparable` as well:

> Finally, the implementor must ensure that `x.compareTo(y)==0` implies that `sgn(x.compareTo(z)) == sgn(y.compareTo(z))`, for all `z`.

In a less formal way, this says "if two things `x` and `y` are equal (`x.compareTo(y) == 0`), then it does not matter whether I compare `x` or `y` to something else, the result must be the same (`x.compareTo(z) == y.compareTo(z)`<sup>1</sup>)."

How can we break it? Let us assume we have two `Student`s `s1` and `s2` with `s1.compareTo(s2) != 0`. Let's assume further that we have a Person `p3` with `p3.compareTo(s1) == 0` and `p3.compareTo(2) == 0`.  Because `p3.compareTo(s1) == 0` and `p3.compareTo(s2) == 0`, the contract demands that `s1.compareTo(s2) == 0`. That is a contradiction.

There is an alternative in form of [`Comparator<T>`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html). You separate the sort criteria from the actual object.

For your example, it might look like this:

```
public class StudentComparator implements Comparator<Student> {

    @Override
    public int compare(Student o1, Student o2) {
        int comp = o1.name.compareTo(o2.name);
        if (comp == 0) {
            comp = o1.age - o2.age;
            if (comp == 0) {
                comp = o1.groupId - o2.groupId;
            }
        }
        return comp;
    }
}
```

---

**Acknowledgement**

I initially thought that it should be possible to onverride `compareTo(...)` in a way that does not break the contract. But @user2357112 taught me the opposite =). Thank you for pointing out my two mistakes!

---

<sub><sup>1</sup>I neglected the `sgn(...)` for readability.</sub>

Comment: I initially thought we could use a `compareTo` implementation like what you suggest, but it still breaks the contract of `Comparable`, because two students could compare equal to a non-student Person and yet compare unequal to each other. There simply isn't any way for `Student` to change the comparison logic between students without breaking the contract.

Comment: The Comparator is the way to go.

Comment: Still broken. First, you're testing `that instanceof Person` and then casting `that` to `Student`. That's probably a typo. Even if you test `that instanceof Student`, though, it still fails in the same case I mentioned before; we could have `studentOne.compareTo(person) == 0` and `studentTwo.compareTo(person) == 0`, but `studentOne.compareTo(studentTwo) != 0`.

Comment: Thanks for your advice @Turing85. Your explanation was great. I have used the first solution and now it works properly.

Comment: @Szadury I hope by "first solution", you mean the `Comparator` solution? All other "solution" break the contract of `Comparable` and thus are broken.

Comment: To be honest the program worked for me and I have no clue why it is "broken"

Comment: @Szadury re-read my answer from the part that starts with "Let us try to not break the contract".

Answer (score 0):

I think it's comparing them as `Person`s because you've implemented  `Comparable<Person>` in the `Student` class:

```
public class Student extends Person implements Comparable<Person>
```

Try replacing with

```
public class Student extends Person implements Comparable<Student>
```

Comment: Can't do that, because superclass Person already has Comparable<Person> and it cannot be implemented more than once and with different types